# How to replace part of IP Address in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to replace ***certain part of IP Address in a batch file***.

Lets say there is a variable

```
set ip=10.20.45.254
```

or

```
set ip=10.20.45.2
```

and i have to change **the last part** to **1** like

```
10.20.45.254 -> 10.20.45.1
```

I have tried to check this manual http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html
but I am not sure how to detect exactly the last part of IP because it can have different length...

Is it possible todo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in batch (replace test.txt with your file name)

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a in (test.txt) do (echo %%a.%%b.%%c.1)
```

**P.S. Try  this...**

```
rem -----------------------------------------
rem  Imagine that %line has some IP string...
SET  _IP=%line:~4% 
ECHO IP: %_IP%         
rem -----------------------------------------
timeout /t 2
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a IN ("%_IP%") DO ( 
set gate=%%a.%%b.%%c.1 
)
ECHO Gateway IP: %gate%
```

Take care of the qoutes, they are essential  `("%_IP%")`.

Comment: Would you mind to change code so it gets IP from some variable, please?

Comment: `for /?` shows you how to: `... in ("%var%") do ...`

Comment: why should it? The quotes tell `for` to treat it as text, not as a filename.

Comment: @Stephan Look, when I execute only this line of code `SET _IP="12.45.2.123"

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a IN (%_IP%) DO echo %%a.%%b.%%c.1

pause
` then it works fine. But when i do the same from more complex batch file it gives message that it cannot find the file and display IP consuming from %_IP%

Comment: @Stephan It like for doesnt recognize that %_IP% is a string and not a filename.

Comment: take care of the qoutes, they are essential. In your question you `set ip=10.20.45.254`, in your comment you `SET _IP="12.45.2.123"`

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
set ip=10.20.45.254
for %%a in (%ip%) do echo %%~Na.1
```

This method works also if the IP's are stored as lines inside a file:

```
for /F %%a in (ipList.txt) do echo %%~Na.1
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this to enter in an IP address that you want with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

```
@echo off 
echo "Enter Static IP" 
echo "Static IP Address:" 
set /p IP_Addr=

netsh interface ip set address <Name of Network Adapter> static %IP_Addr% 255.255.255.0
```

You can always add in a section to ask for subnet, or just hard code it.